# Return data frames sequentially

Tags: r

Let's say I have a custom function `x` that takes an argument `y` and returns a dataframe `df` that corresponds to that argument. `x(y)` displays `df`. (After the necessary manipulation, the final line of function `x` reads`View(df)`)

Now, I have a character vector `z` of different values of `y` for all of which I need to see the dataframes individually. Running a `for` loop for `z` just displays the dataframe associated with the last value of `z`

How do I run a loop of `z` such that the dataframes corresponding to individual values are displayed sequentially - i.e, the first dataframe is displayed, and after I press enter (or something) it displays the next one

Comment: Please share a reproducible example, expected output and your attempt. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `a` for your vector of interest:

```
a = rnorm(10)
x <- function(y) {
  for (df in y) {
    View(df)
    readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
  }
}
x(a)
```